# Story about "simple Teshuva" via never telling a lie

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends

I read a story over shabbas from [Tales of Tzaddikim, Bamidbar](http://www.artscroll.com/Products/ta4h.html) pg 251-252, Published by Mesorah Publications, and it quoted it from Sefer Chassidim, Siman 6407. I opened up my Sefer Chassidim and the last entry in it is 1172 ([like this one, for example](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32456&pgnum=286)).

The basics to the story is of a man wanting to do teshuva and goes before a Tzaddik to ask how. The Rebbe tells him it is simple, all he has to do is never tell a lie. As a result, every time he wanted to do something wrong, he would say to himself, what will i say to someone who asks me about what I have done, thus, stopping himself from doing something wrong.

Is there another Sefer Chassidim or another way that it was organized? Is there another source for this story?

Comment: Eldad, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Comment: IIRC it's a midrash and the rabbi is R' Shimon ben Shetach. But I'd have to look it up.

Comment: @Shalom: see the Pnei Dovid quoted here:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29879/603 . You can see it in the Ayuma Kanidgalot as well, but it is barely legible.

Answer (score 5):

It is a typo. The correct number is [Sefer Chasidim 647](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32456&st=&pgnum=197&hilite=).

Answer (score 2):

The [Brit Olam](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32456&st=&pgnum=197&hilite=) (commentary on the Sefer Chasidim) brings three sources for this story:

- Sefer [Auma Kanidgalot](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21437&st=&pgnum=21)
- Sefer Masiot Katan (couldn't find a source for this)
- [Pnei Dovid](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40237&pgnum=16)

Sefer Auma Kanidgalot and Pnei Dovid quote similar stories, however, they are slightly different versions.

Pnei Dovid says the story takes place with a "Rav", where as, Sefer Auma Kanidgalot quotes the Rav as being R' Shimon Ben Shatach.

Comment: Anyone know what the Sefer Ma'asiot Katan is? According to a footnote here - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51462&hilite=0ceccc25-a5eb-4d36-b2bc-2458051a5b7b&st=%d7%9e%d7%a2%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%95%d7%aa+%d7%a7%d7%98%d7%9f -, it is this - http://hebrewbooks.org/33917 - , but I couldn't find the story there.